# Delphi bitwise operation question

Tags: delphi, bit-manipulation

F0 7D 00 C8 00
->11110000 01111101 00000000 11001000 00000000

First 4 bits 1111=15 means, next 30 bits are used to store 2 values,15 bits each,
a=000001111101000=1000,b=000001100100000=800 (Signed-bit value)

1111000001111101000000001100100000 is paded with '000000' so it'll be 5 bytes.

How to make such a delphi procedure to change the value a & b,

procedure setBit(a,b:Integer);

Comment: What would you like to change the values a and b *to*? Can you give some example input and output for this setBit function? What form should the output take?

Comment: It looks like a homework assignment... are you really asking us to code that for you?  I think you may want to show some effort first in order to get some help. ;)

Comment: Where does the data come from? An array of bytes? A binary stream?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Bitboy. What you've asked here obviously isn't very clear. Please use the "edit" link on the left to change your question and address the confusion that others and I have expressed. Your question seems interesting, and I'd like to answer it, but right now, I still have no idea what you're really asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use LSB storage order.

Try this:

```
procedure SetBit(const a,b: cardinal; var dest);
var d: Int64 absolute dest;
begin
  d := $F000000000+(Int64(a) shl 21)+b shl 6;
end;
```

It will change the 8 bytes value pointed by dest, storing the data into the first 5 bytes.

Comment: Why do you use an untyped output variable? That might also be confusing for someone not familiar with bit operations.

Comment: @Jens the procedure prototype in the question didn't have any destination variable... and an untyped output variable is somewhat less confusing as a pointer... you can use such for i := 0 to 100 do SetBit(i,i*2,aArray[i]), with aArray: array[0..100,0..4] of byte

Comment: but in all cases, the question was unclear, about LSB/MSB order to use.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set a bit is to use the assembler instruction BTS. Something alike (not tested)

```
procedure SetBit(var L; bit: Longint);
asm
  BTS [EAX], EDX
end;
```

should work. See http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf

Comment: It will definitively work. But the purpose of the question was to set two 15 bit values inside a bit array of 5 bytes length.